# npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

Creating a new React app in **E:\Dokuman Visual Code\react.js\project-app**.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

```
npm ERR! code EBADF
npm ERR! EBADF: bad file descriptor, write

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\FIKCROS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-05T01_02_39_053Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting project-app/ from E:\Dokuman Visual Code\react.js
Done.
```

Comment: Try using LTS version, it fixes mine.

Comment: Hope this working.
`npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact issue.
Things that worked to me was:
I had changed my terminal for VSCode  from Powershell to bash (restarting terminal should help ).

Run the following commands:

1. Run **npm cache clean --force**
2. Then Run **npx create-react-app (project name)**

Hope this should help you

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this problem, I migrated to version 14 of node (minimum version to create a react application) and try again

**1**- **Install NVM**

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

**2 - Install node v14**

```
nvm install 14
```

**3 - switch to node  v14**

```
nvm use 14
```

**4 - Retry Again**

```
npx create-react-app project-name
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `npm cache clean --force`
2. Disable any third party antivirus you use and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a different network, either a different Wi-Fi network or using a mobile hotspot. Then, try again to create the react app:

```bash
$ npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands:

1. `npm install -g create-react-app-offline`
2. `crao -n <app-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout from 30s to 100s

```
npm set timeout=100000
```

then

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And finally create you app/project